# MySQL: Select whether or not user is in another table

Tags: mysql

*Keep in mind there's more to both the statement and the tables, but I'll keep it short for easier reading.*

I'm trying to get whether or not a user has been in a shop or not. The tables look like this.

```
--Shop--
ShopID

--Visit--
ShopID
UserID
```

And the following is how far I've come at the moment.

```
SELECT shop.ShopID, visit.UserID AS Visited FROM shop
LEFT OUTER JOIN visit ON shop.ShopID = visit.ShopID
WHERE UserID = 1
```

The problem with this code is that it will not show NULL for visits that's not UserID 1. I've tried to add `OR UserID IS NULL` to the statement, but it just leaves me with all the shops that has not been visited by any user.

I could filter it by checking whether `Visited` is the same as the UserID or not, but it would be a lot easier if the database could write it as 1 and 0. So to ask specific:

How do I make `Visited` output 0 or 1 based on if there's a UserID 1 connected with the ShopID in the Visit-table?

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result.

Comment: So you only want to join in shops that have been visited by someone?  That is, if there is a shop that no one has visited, you want it excluded from the results?

Comment: What exactly do you want? The list of all shops a particular user has been to?

Comment: It seems you want a RIGHT JOIN or, better, simply reverse the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dennis Klopfer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32162680/4261176) is the way to go for simplicity and performance. But maybe you want something more like that, to check if a given user **ever** visited each shop:

```
shop |  visited by user 1
 #1  |       false
 #2  |       true
```

If that's the case, I'd try something like this:

```
   SELECT s.ShopID, IF(ISNULL(v.UserID), FALSE, TRUE) AS visited
     FROM shop S LEFT JOIN visit v ON s.ShopID = v.ShopID AND v.UserID = 1
```

Of course, you can also add a `WHERE` clause to your query and filter the shop list by any field.

Comment: This is the one. Shows all the shops regardless of visits and shows whether `User 1` has been in each shop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your join is that you keep all the 'shopID's in the list, as you just create a list which expands all the `shop`s and `visit`s with the `shop`s that have not been visited. If I get you right what you want is the `shop`s visited by `user = 1`. This can be achieved very easily by just using the `Visit` table.

```
Select DISTINCT visit.shopID FROM visit
WHERE UserID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT shop.ShopID, if(visit.UserID is null,0,1) AS Visited FROM shop
LEFT OUTER JOIN visit ON (shop.ShopID = visit.ShopID
AND visit.UserID = 1 )
```

Comment: The WHERE would make the if always false. `WHERE UserID = 1 OR UserID IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to accomplish this, I think:

```
SELECT s.ShopID, v.UserID AS Visited
FROM shop s LEFT OUTER JOIN
     visit v
     ON s.ShopID = v.ShopID AND v.UserID = 1;
```

You need to put the condition on `v` in the `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause.

However, if a user can visit multiple times, then you'll get multiple rows.  So, I would recommend using a subquery in the `SELECT` to get an arbitrary row with the user:

```
select s.ShopId,
       (select v.UserId
        from visit v
        where s.SHopId = v.ShopId and v.userId = 1
        limit 1
       ) as UserId
from shop s;
```